# Android - can't get component to appear below linear layout

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to get a text component to appear at the bottom of my layout. The whole layout is just an outer Linear layout containing a TextView, an ImageView, a horizontal Linear Layout with two buttons, and finally the TextView (that doesn't display). Note that when I put the same TextView *above* the LinearLayout with buttons, the TextView shows up.

Problematic layout code is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/splash_text" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:padding="30dp" android:textStyle="italic" android:text="@string/splash_text" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/splash_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"></ImageView>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/start_button" android:text="@string/start_quiz"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/exit_button" android:text="@string/exit_quiz"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"

                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/splash_text2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

        android:padding="1dp" 
        android:textSize="1sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textStyle="italic" android:text="@string/splash_text2" />
```

Comment: Did you fail to close the outer `LinearLayout` or is that just a typo?

Comment: Are both `LinearLayout` elements supposed to use id `android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"`?

Comment: Both are typos as I've been changing it around a fair amount. However,  still no love when they are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. The problem was that the inner LinearLayout was set to "fill_parent". When I changed it to "wrap_content", everything underneath it appeared.